# extract data from interactive graph

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the data from this interactive chart which is located at the bottom of the website below: https://www.vgchartz.com/tools/hw_date.php?reg=USA&ending=Yearly

I've used developer tools in chrome but cannot find the data points in the elements tab.

Would appreciate if someone can take a look and tell me if the data points are stored on the page somewhere or there is any way to do using Python

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is included inside `<script>` tag on that page. To parse it, you can use [`js2py`](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/) library. For example:

```py
import ast
import js2py
import requests


url = "https://www.vgchartz.com/tools/hw_date.php?reg=USA&ending=Yearly"

data = re.search(
    r"StockChart\(({.*?})\);", requests.get(url).text, flags=re.S
).group(1)

data = js2py.eval_js("data = " + data + ";")
data = ast.literal_eval(str(data))

print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "chart": {
        "endOnTick": False,
        "marginBottom": 90,
        "marginLeft": 80,
        "marginRight": 20,
        "renderTo": "chart_container",
        "startOnTick": False,
        "zoomType": "y",
    },
    "legend": {"enabled": True},
    "plotOptions": {"series": {"dataGrouping": {"smoothed": True}}},
    "rangeSelector": {"selected": 5},
    "series": [
        {
            "cropThreshold": 1,
            "data": [
                {"x": 1072933200000, "y": 1302609},
                {"x": 1104555600000, "y": 2604003},
                {"x": 1136091600000, "y": 5074726},
                {"x": 1167627600000, "y": 8757992},
                {"x": 1199163600000, "y": 10156740},
                {"x": 1230786000000, "y": 10369446},
                {"x": 1262322000000, "y": 8434877},
                {"x": 1293858000000, "y": 4335275},
                {"x": 1325394000000, "y": 2164269},
                {"x": 1357016400000, "y": 600849},
            ],


...
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but How I could get it like a dataframe that shows all values for each object by years?

Answer (score 0):

The chart data is imbedded in the HTML response of a basic `GET` request to the link. The data points themselves can be found in a Javascript `Object` formatted in a `script` tag. To pull these points, you will need to use some sort of Javascript parser to access the `Object` and convert the JS object representation to a Python dictionary. Pure JSON parsing cannot easily be used here, since the `Object` is not initialized in valid JSON syntax. The code below uses the module [`pyjsparser`](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/pyjsparser) which can be installed via `pip`: `pip3 install pyjsparser`.

```
import requests, pyjsparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

d = soup(requests.get('https://www.vgchartz.com/tools/hw_date.php?reg=USA&ending=Yearly'), 'html.parser')
ast = pyjsparser.parse(d.select_one('#chart_body > .chart_date_selector ~ script').text)

def to_json(ast):
  if ast['type'] == 'ArrayExpression':
     return [to_json(i) for i in ast['elements']]
  if ast['type'] == 'ObjectExpression':
     return {i['key']['name']:to_json(i['value']) for i in ast['properties']}
  if ast['type'] == 'Literal': 
     return ast['value']

def get_chart_data(ast):
  if isinstance(ast, dict):
     if ast.get('type') == 'Property' and ast['key']['name'] == 'series'  and ast['value']['type'] == 'ArrayExpression':
        yield to_json(ast['value'])
        return
     for b in ast.values():
        yield from get_chart_data(b)
  elif isinstance(ast, list):
     for i in ast:
        yield from get_chart_data(i)

data = next(get_chart_data(ast))
```

Output:

```
[{'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'PSP', 'data': [{'x': 1072933200000.0, 'y': 0.0}, {'x': 1104555600000.0, 'y': 3527367.0}, {'x': 1136091600000.0, 'y': 2952955.0}, {'x': 1167627600000.0, 'y': 3563757.0}, {'x': 1199163600000.0, 'y': 3815680.0}, {'x': 1230786000000.0, 'y': 2452361.0}, {'x': 1262322000000.0, 'y': 1824105.0}, {'x': 1293858000000.0, 'y': 1245169.0}, {'x': 1325394000000.0, 'y': 274023.0}, {'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 128378.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 26999.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'Wii', 'data': [{'x': 1136091600000.0, 'y': 1075329.0}, {'x': 1167627600000.0, 'y': 6444409.0}, {'x': 1199163600000.0, 'y': 9826502.0}, {'x': 1230786000000.0, 'y': 8989309.0}, {'x': 1262322000000.0, 'y': 7398500.0}, {'x': 1293858000000.0, 'y': 4878060.0}, {'x': 1325394000000.0, 'y': 2042064.0}, {'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 773488.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 216453.0}, {'x': 1420088400000.0, 'y': 58765.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'X360', 'data': [{'x': 1104555600000.0, 'y': 563282.0}, {'x': 1136091600000.0, 'y': 3832778.0}, {'x': 1167627600000.0, 'y': 4356599.0}, {'x': 1199163600000.0, 'y': 4784134.0}, {'x': 1230786000000.0, 'y': 4691537.0}, {'x': 1262322000000.0, 'y': 6999773.0}, {'x': 1293858000000.0, 'y': 7777810.0}, {'x': 1325394000000.0, 'y': 6488715.0}, {'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 3164108.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 855780.0}, {'x': 1420088400000.0, 'y': 165018.0}, {'x': 1451624400000.0, 'y': 67456.0}, {'x': 1483246800000.0, 'y': 5433.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'DS', 'data': [{'x': 1072933200000.0, 'y': 1302609.0}, {'x': 1104555600000.0, 'y': 2604003.0}, {'x': 1136091600000.0, 'y': 5074726.0}, {'x': 1167627600000.0, 'y': 8757992.0}, {'x': 1199163600000.0, 'y': 10156740.0}, {'x': 1230786000000.0, 'y': 10369446.0}, {'x': 1262322000000.0, 'y': 8434877.0}, {'x': 1293858000000.0, 'y': 4335275.0}, {'x': 1325394000000.0, 'y': 2164269.0}, {'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 600849.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'PS3', 'data': [{'x': 1136091600000.0, 'y': 667762.0}, {'x': 1167627600000.0, 'y': 2474435.0}, {'x': 1199163600000.0, 'y': 3547363.0}, {'x': 1230786000000.0, 'y': 4255949.0}, {'x': 1262322000000.0, 'y': 4737437.0}, {'x': 1293858000000.0, 'y': 4486935.0}, {'x': 1325394000000.0, 'y': 3480788.0}, {'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 2237467.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 721523.0}, {'x': 1420088400000.0, 'y': 274884.0}, {'x': 1451624400000.0, 'y': 125072.0}, {'x': 1483246800000.0, 'y': 12482.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': '3DS', 'data': [{'x': 1293858000000.0, 'y': 4056029.0}, {'x': 1325394000000.0, 'y': 3542069.0}, {'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 3905067.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 2518536.0}, {'x': 1420088400000.0, 'y': 2499074.0}, {'x': 1451624400000.0, 'y': 2456456.0}, {'x': 1483246800000.0, 'y': 2060575.0}, {'x': 1514782800000.0, 'y': 1534418.0}, {'x': 1546318800000.0, 'y': 615394.0}, {'x': 1577854800000.0, 'y': 249847.0}, {'x': 1609477200000.0, 'y': 2787.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'PSV', 'data': [{'x': 1293858000000.0, 'y': 0.0}, {'x': 1325394000000.0, 'y': 1227049.0}, {'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 509085.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 324396.0}, {'x': 1420088400000.0, 'y': 247162.0}, {'x': 1451624400000.0, 'y': 108422.0}, {'x': 1483246800000.0, 'y': 20908.0}, {'x': 1514782800000.0, 'y': 3119.0}, {'x': 1546318800000.0, 'y': 0.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'WiiU', 'data': [{'x': 1325394000000.0, 'y': 899502.0}, {'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 1214283.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 1565573.0}, {'x': 1420088400000.0, 'y': 1361771.0}, {'x': 1451624400000.0, 'y': 460025.0}, {'x': 1483246800000.0, 'y': 9553.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'PS4', 'data': [{'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 2072802.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 4656798.0}, {'x': 1420088400000.0, 'y': 5802890.0}, {'x': 1451624400000.0, 'y': 5077809.0}, {'x': 1483246800000.0, 'y': 5404655.0}, {'x': 1514782800000.0, 'y': 5245644.0}, {'x': 1546318800000.0, 'y': 3824746.0}, {'x': 1577854800000.0, 'y': 2084519.0}, {'x': 1609477200000.0, 'y': 613650.0}, {'x': 1641013200000.0, 'y': 168996.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'XOne', 'data': [{'x': 1357016400000.0, 'y': 1928445.0}, {'x': 1388552400000.0, 'y': 4325832.0}, {'x': 1420088400000.0, 'y': 4938473.0}, {'x': 1451624400000.0, 'y': 4696984.0}, {'x': 1483246800000.0, 'y': 4307564.0}, {'x': 1514782800000.0, 'y': 4304447.0}, {'x': 1546318800000.0, 'y': 2971031.0}, {'x': 1577854800000.0, 'y': 1508975.0}, {'x': 1609477200000.0, 'y': 503439.0}, {'x': 1641013200000.0, 'y': 22086.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'NS', 'data': [{'x': 1483246800000.0, 'y': 4880477.0}, {'x': 1514782800000.0, 'y': 5613050.0}, {'x': 1546318800000.0, 'y': 6479134.0}, {'x': 1577854800000.0, 'y': 9027556.0}, {'x': 1609477200000.0, 'y': 8012707.0}, {'x': 1641013200000.0, 'y': 2163947.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'PS5', 'data': [{'x': 1577854800000.0, 'y': 1940361.0}, {'x': 1609477200000.0, 'y': 4302047.0}, {'x': 1641013200000.0, 'y': 1328693.0}]}, {'showLastLabel': True, 'cropThreshold': 1.0, 'name': 'XS', 'data': [{'x': 1577854800000.0, 'y': 1525675.0}, {'x': 1609477200000.0, 'y': 3893991.0}, {'x': 1641013200000.0, 'y': 1937560.0}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but How I could get it like a dataframe that shows all values for each object by years?